# Grep not giving proper return code

Tags: linux, unix

While searching for multiple patterns in a file and finding the return code using grep command i am getting the same results whether the patter is present or not please help me regarding this below is my code

```
grep -v "ORA-|Linux-x86_64 Error|stopped|Failed" /home/expdp.log>/dev/null
```

echo $?

Output is always 0  wheter file having pattern or not

Comment: how do you know if the pattern was found or not if you redirecting to `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with $? you get the return value from the program, if it's run well or not. its not about the pattern match. you should parse the returned stout output instead of redirecting it to /dev/null/

you can use the -c option to just count the matches and evaluate the returned count value.

Comment: I am not able to get it can you please provide me example

Comment: `grep -c "ORA-|Linux-x86_64 Error|stopped|Failed"  /home/expdp.log `

Comment: by the way, why you are use `-v`   do you want all lines not including your selection?